# Display a pointer value with lldb debugger

Tags: c++, c, debugging, lldb

I'm working in a personal project of open-source technologies developing an application build it in C. I'm using the **lldb** debugger tool.

My question is simple: How can I display or show the values of an element when I'm debugging.

For example:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main(){

 char phrase[1024];
 int i=0;

 for(i=0;i<1024;i++){
    printf("%c",phrase[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

In the lldb prompt, I can see the values for specific character of the array:

```
lldb>b 6
lldb>frame variable phrase[0];
```

When I want to execute:

```
lldb>frame variable phrase[i]
```

I got an error: "*unable to find any variable expression path that matches 'phrase[i]'*"

Comment: can you see `*(phrase+i)`

Comment: It gives me an error message: no variable named _'(phrase' found in this frame._

Comment: You can't display the value of a variable expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
(lldb) expr phrase[i]
```

or equivalently

```
(lldb) p phrase[i]
```

for that

frame variable supports constant indexes (i.e. plain ol’ numbers), but if you need to use a variable or anything BUT a number, you need to use the expression command

As a caveat, the behavior of frame var vs. expression might be different in some cases when doing array-like access. This won’t affect your example (but it would if you were using an std::vector, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, I was still testing and you came with the answer. Great!

Comment: For those coming from gdb, "expr" or "p" are equivalent to gdb's "print" command, and "frame var" is some combination of "info locals"/"info args"/"info variables", except it supports a very simple dereference/array access syntax as well.